How do I declare the CreatedBy field to be null for serialization but non null for database?
In my class, my field Name is marked as [Required] so Entity Framework can mark it as non-nullable in the migration:
public class MyClass
{
   [Required]
   public string? CreatedBy {get;set;}
}

But the CreatedBy field is set at creation on the server, so the first time it must travel as NULL from the client
I get a serialization error:

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1
['The CreatedBy field is required.']

How do I declare the CreatedBy field to be null for serialization but non null for database?

Use two different classes: MyClassEntity for Entity Framework and MyClassDTO for serialization.

@AlexanderPetrov I have added your solution to my answer post. thx.

If it is set on the server then you should mark the property as ValueGeneratedOnAdd and HasDefaultValue(...). Let EF handle all of it. Don't mix in logic of other components/stacks, that makes it utterly muddy.

@GertArnold, that sounds like the answer

How exactly is the property set "on the server"? By a database default constraint?

on my controller, it's using jwt auth, It grabs the information of the authenticated user, (User.Identity)

But that's different. There are three parties involved here and it depends on one's perspective what is called "client" or "server". I tend to see a web application as a "client" application to a database "server" (hence my first comment) but it's equally valid to see a web application as a web "server" to a UI "client". In the latter case (yours) the "server" is the EF application that sets the property, not the database. Which means: you do have to allow it arrive as null from the UI.

... Which means (as I see it) that it's never to be marked as required in UI objects. For new entities you set it in the controller, for existing entities you just ignore it when saving changes.

Solution 1:
Just use a DTO object and an Entity object with different attributes.
Solution 2:
Remove the Required-Attribute and set the CreatedBy field as required in OnModelCreating():
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<MyClass>()
        .Property(x => x.CreatedBy)
        .IsRequired();
}

Solution 3:
Disable validation of Required-Attribute:
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);

...

builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options
    => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);


I would go with a combination of Solution 1 and Solution 2.


Since I don't want to use fluent api for this, I decided to disable the serialization validation:
program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);

...

builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options
    => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);

...



I´ve smmarized all  three possible solutions in my answer. check it out please.
